# Portable Linux environment for applications

Tags: c, linux, windows, virtual-machine

Is there any application (maybe a VM) that run Linux compatible compiled programs (like a web service) on other platforms (like windows) like an native application?
for example executive a C coded web service that is compiled by that application like a native linux programming but with an extra layer.
I think it have to be an x86 VM like QEMU but that is so heavy and complicated.
my problem is that I coded an application in C for linux but not I want to run it on others platforms without rebuilding that or using Cygwin.

Comment: Windows 10 now has support for running linux programs - search google for `Windows Subsystem for Linux` or `WSL`

Comment: @Dipstick it's not recommended for production by Microsoft

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Docker](https://docker.com). As far as I know, it is possible to run Docker images that were built on Linux on Windows.

Comment: Docker is not very portable I'm looking for solution like docker but more portable and more simple

Answer (score 0):

I found an incomplete but best match solution to my problem:
[flinix](https://github.com/wishstudio/flinux/)
I hope more contribution to this awesome project.

Answer (score -1):

Softwares like wine have been made for linux to run Windows applications. You can try http://www.andlinux.org/ to run linux apps in Windows.

You can uses VirtualBox or VMWare and run a Linux VM or use Cygwin or MinGW (similar to cygwin). Maybe try with Babun which is really easy but I'm not sure this would run a linux app...

Comment: exactly I'm looking something like WineHQ for Windows.